# Disable or make the Kendo Editor Read-only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I am using **Kendo UI** Editors in one of my pages.
Below is the syntax used.

```
$("#editorKendo1").kendoEditor();
$("#editorKendo2").kendoEditor();
```

I want to either disable or make both of the editors read-only on some condition and make it editable on some other condition.

Below are the links to the similar requirement i have got so far.
[How can i disable kendo editor in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182896/how-can-i-disable-kendo-editor-in-asp-net-mvc)
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/editor/making-the-editor-disabled-readonly.aspx

I am using **Kendo UI** Web, **Version - 2012.3.1114**
Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Check this official reference http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/editor/overview#configuration-Apply

Answer (score 10):

Answers there are still valid for Kendo. You do not need the editor if you are going to just show the content.

Anyway

```
$($('#editorName').data().kendoEditor.body).attr('contenteditable',false)
```

Comment: But we can delete the content right..? (by backspacing or entering delete in the keyboard) Do you know a way of disabling backspace and delete keys in the contenteditable="false" div ? 

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/immutable-elements