# How to disable Kendo UI Editor completely including shortcuts

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have tried the following:

[Disable or make the Kendo Editor Read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207703/disable-or-make-the-kendo-editor-read-only)

and also disabled keydown/keyup/keypress, but there is an event the fires underline, bold, etc. via shortcuts (ctrl + b, ctrl + u).

I want disable everything and make the editor read only or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a true way to disable the editor so I found a work around just now.

```
$("#editorSelector").off("keyup keydown keypress");
```

I turn off the event and rebind the events.